# Angular bootstrap - unable to disable dropdown menu according to filtering result

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I'm using `Angular 1.5` and `Angular Bootstrap`. I have a `uib-dropdown` element with a list, and a custom filter. The items presented in the list are obviously filtered according to the custom filter, the final goal is to **disable** the `dropdown` and add a text placeholder if there are no items after the filtering process (until the user changes the input that will meet the filtering requirement).

This is the HTML code:

```
        <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
            <button id="customHtmlBtn"
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-default"
                    uib-dropdown-toggle>
                {{selectedHtml.name}}<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
                <li ng-repeat="html in customHtmls | filter: $ctrl.customFilter as filteredCount">
                    <a ng-click="htmlSelected(html)">{{html.name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

JS code inside the controller:

```
        this.htmlSnippetSizeFilter = function (html) {
            return html.width === 100 && html.height === 100;
        };
```

How can I use the `filteredCount` (in case it is ==0) syntax to disable the `uib-dropdown`?

Comment: Try <button nd-disabled="filteredCount.length === 0"> Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks, it did the job. Do you know of any way to add a placeholder to the dropdown along with the disabled attribute?

Comment: Depends what do you mean by placeholder - button value, ad-hoc option, or something other?

Comment: A placeholder like `input` element has, some text that will be shown on a certain condition, to indicate an invalid action, when the button is disabled to have certain text on it.

Comment: I would just go for <button>{{filteredCount.length === 0 ? 'Sum Ting Wong' : selectedHtml.name}}</button> But I don't know that fits your needs